# Dragging object out of screen (automatic scrolling on dragging at screen edge)

Tags: android, view, drag-and-drop, scroll, drag

I am creating an android app in which I want to scroll down(or up) when I reach the bottom(or top) of the screen of the device (not necessarily bottom of layout , only bottom of visible screen height) while dragging an object .Think of it as if you want to drag some object out of the screen . Have searched the entire internet ... but no solution till far .Really need help here ,thanks.

Comment: Define an area at top and bottom. If the finger is in this area, scroll automatically upward/downward in reasonable speed

Comment: Also , I am not able to get the Y-value of the visible screen to compare with , so that I could scroll after some threshold value.

Comment: Look at docs for View.setTouchDelegate(). For more details you should show some of your code

Comment: I am trying to use the solution from your first comment, but I am not sure what area to use ...I tried a lot many things (like a linear layout , a view , a button etc.) but the onDragListener() method just won't work with them :( ... not sure why ... also other listeners are not working on it ...

Comment: Also, why do some objects get hidden by other objects ... like layouts ? Somehow the layout and views are not letting the listeneres of the button to work ,by coming on top of the button I  think ...